# Heroku unable to possess routes starting from '@' at express-router in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mongoose, passport.js

I have pushed a simple app made by NodeJS, Express and MongoDB *using Mongoose* to Heroku, but one of my router is not working properly.

I had made a router starting form `@` for displaying user's profile, which is working fine on my localhost, but is throwing me back to error page when in production at Heroku.

Is using `@` a wrong convention at Heroku? Any fix?

Here are the snapshots:

**At production stage of heroku**:
[image]

**Same route at localhost**:
[image]

**Here is my router config:** at `routes.js`:
I am using PassportJs for user authentication.

```
app.get('/@:username', sabSettings, function(req, res) {
    var currentUser = req.user;
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({ 'local.username': req.params.username }, function(err, user) {
            var usertofind = user;
            if (err)
                throw err;
            if (!user)
                res.render('profile/p404', {
                    title: req.params.username + ' Not Found | eduBird',
                    setting: req.setting,
                    usertofind: req.params.username,
                    user: currentUser ? currentUser : 'ann'
                });
            else {
                res.render('profile/display', {
                    title: usertofind.local.name + ' Profile | eduBird',
                    setting: req.setting,
                    user: currentUser ? currentUser : 'ann',
                    requser: usertofind
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This system is working fine for every user at localhost, but not working at Heroku.

Your suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got that solved myself.
Actually it was the problem of `.pug` and not the Heroku server. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459442/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-pug/42459443#42459443) was the main error, which browser showed, and how I fixed.